# how to insert record in table from cfloop result set modified record only in coldfusion

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to identify the modified record from result set loop..I need to find modified record and insert in to other table in coldfusion.

My result set

```
 <cfquery name="xyz" datasource="xyz">
  Select * from Table_xyz
    </cfquery>

  <form name="ABC" action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">
   <table id="tbl" cellpadding="1" border="1px" style="width:100px">    
    <tr bgcolor="##3333CC">                 
     <td width="60"><font size=-1 color="White">Account</font></td>      
        <td width="250"><font size=-1 color="White">Description</font></td>      
        <td width="150"><font size=-1 color="White">PRD</font></td>     
       <td width="200"><font size=-1 color="White">$$/Month</font></td>  
    </tr>
    <cfoutput query="xyz> 
       <tr> 
       <td><input type="text" name="acct" value="#acct#"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="desc" value="#Description#"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="PRD" value="#PRM#"></td> 
       <td><input type="text" name="PRM" value="#PRM#"></td>
      </tr> 
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

  </cfoutput>
```

[image]

Comment: ... we're going to need a lot more information than that. How do you know which record is modified? Do you mean when a user modified a textbox?

Comment: @Matt - If user modify any result set value..and submit the page..we needto identify that modified value and insert in to table..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the key:

```
<cfoutput query="xyz"> 
  <tr> 
    <td><input type="text" value="#acct#"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="#Description#"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="#PRM#"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" value="#PRM#"></td>
  </tr>
```

Currently there is no name attribute for these form fields.  You need one, and it needs to include something to identify the record.  Something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="xyz"> 
  <tr> 
    <td><input type="text" name="acct#id#" value="#acct#"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description#id#" value="#Description#"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prm#id#" value="#PRM#"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="something#id#" value="#PRM#"></td>
  </tr>
```

Then add hidden fields.  Here is an example for acct.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="orig_acct#id#" value="#acct#">
```

This is still in the cfoutput block.  When the form is submitted you can compare what the user had in the textboxes to what was in the hidden fields.  That will identify changes and you can take the necessary action.

Comment: The result set coming in the loop more than 50 records..How do i know which one is modified record and how do i update or insert into table those updated values?..Thanks!

Comment: How do you interpret the last two sentences of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer might be to just do the insert in the new table at the time the user submits their update.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>
<cfquery name="abc" datasource="xyz">
        INSERT INTO Table_abc VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.acct#">
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.desc#">
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.PRD#">
            ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.PRM#">
            ) 
    </cfquery>    

    <cfquery name="xyz" datasource="xyz">
        UPDATE Table_xyz SET 
            acct = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.acct#">
            ,Description = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.desc#">
            ,PRD = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.PRD#">
            ,PRM = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.PRM#">
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

If for some reason it's not possible to do that I would try adding something like a modified_flag and/or modified_timestamp fields to the existing table so you can flag records as modified and when they were modified.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>
    <cfquery name="abc" datasource="xyz">
        UPDATE Table_xyz SET 
            acct = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.acct#">
            ,Description = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.desc#">
            ,PRD = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.PRD#">
            ,PRM = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.PRM#">
            ,modified_flag = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.modified_flag#">
            ,modified_timestamp = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.modified_timestamp#">
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.id#">
    </cfquery>
</cfif>

<cfquery name="xyz" datasource="xyz">
    Select * from Table_xyz
</cfquery>


<table id="tbl" cellpadding="1" border="1px" style="width:100px">   
    <tr bgcolor="##3333CC">                 
        <td width="60"><font size=-1 color="White">Account</font></td>      
        <td width="250"><font size=-1 color="White">Description</font></td>     
        <td width="150"><font size=-1 color="White">PRD</font></td>    
        <td width="200"><font size=-1 color="White">$$/Month</font></td>  
    </tr>
    <cfoutput query="xyz"> 
    <form name="ABC" action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="#id#">
    <input type="hidden" name="modified_flag" value="y"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="modified_timestamp" value="#DateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss")#">
    <tr> 
        <td><input type="text" name="acct" value="#acct#"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="desc" value="#Description#"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="PRD" value="#PRD#"></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="PRM" value="#PRM#"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </form>

    </cfoutput>
</table>
```

I made a few minor changes to your form.  Most notably, I pulled the form tag inside the output loop so that each record was submitted individually when a user clicks submit and also added an "id" field for each record to give you a way to reliably determine which record the users were updating.  In addition, I moved the submit buttons into the table so they displayed next to the record they function for.

After you've copied the record to the second table you could reset the modified_flag and/or modified_timestamp field so you can determine if the record is edited a second time.